# How to style placeholder attribute across all browsers?

Tags: css, html

I have an element like this `<input type="text" placeholder="lorem ipsum">`.

How do I style this`placeholder` attribute in CSS, so that it works across all browsers?

Comment: You mean you want to know how to style the placeholder text?

Comment: Why "custom"? That property is defined in HTML5

Comment: Placeholder is an HTML5 form attribute which is supported across all modern browsers except IE. http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_form_attributes.asp

Comment: There's already a [topic about this][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2610497/change-an-inputs-html5-placeholder-color-with-css

Comment: @Sjoerd: I think this one is more suitable http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2610497/change-an-inputs-html5-placeholder-color-with-css ;)

Answer (score 6):

Placeholder text in inputs has (in the browsers implementing it so far) a light gray color. To style it, you'll need vendor prefix CSS properties.

```
::-webkit-input-placeholder {
   color: red;
}

:-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 18- */
   color: red;  
}

::-moz-placeholder {  /* Firefox 19+ */
   color: red;  
}

:-ms-input-placeholder {  
   color: red;  
}
```

You may also check this very similar question:

- [Change an HTML5 input's placeholder color with CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2610497/change-an-inputs-html5-placeholder-color-with-css)